# How can I prevent a PassthroughSubject from killing a .sink before concurrent upstream futures finish?

Tags: swift, ios13, combine

I've got a PassthroughSubject that send 30 integers followed by a finish message.

Upon receiving these numbers from the subject, I spawn off a future that sleeps for one second, and completes with the input number * 2.

I use .receiveOn to make sure the futures run concurrently, but this means the finish message also propagates concurrently through the chain
and ends the sink before all futures are finished.

Any RxSwift/Combine wizards out there know how I can make it so the reception of the finish message is delayed by the futures completing?

Here is a playground that implements the described behavior:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

/// Setting up the playground
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

/// Injects numbers 0-30 into combine message stream, and then sends a finish.
func publishNumbers(to subject: PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>) {
    (0..<30).forEach {
        subject.send($0)
    }
    subject.send(completion: .finished)
}
/// Delays for one secont, and completes the future by doubling the input.
func delayAndDoubleNumber(_ int: Int) -> Future<Int, Error> {
    return Future<Int, Error> { complete in
        sleep(1)
        complete(.success(int * 2))
    }
}

// Properties involved in Combine processing chain.
let numbersSubject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Error>()
let processingQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)


// Combine processing chain
numbersSubject
    .receive(on: processingQueue) //Comment this line to observe that all futures finish, and are collected before the finish message kills the sink.
    .flatMap { number in
        return delayAndDoubleNumber(number)
    }
    .collect(4)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("Complete: \(completion)")
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Received Value: \(value)")
    })

publishNumbers(to: numbersSubject)
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, as of Xcode 11 beta 3, use a concurrent queue with Combine. You should be able to by Xcode 11 GM.

Philippe Hausler is an Apple engineer who works on Combine. He said the following on [the official Swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/runloop-main-or-dispatchqueue-main-when-using-combine-scheduler/26635/4):

> Also it is worth noting that the `DispatchQueue` used as a scheduler must always be serial to adhere to the contracts of Combine's operators.

[Then later](https://forums.swift.org/t/runloop-main-or-dispatchqueue-main-when-using-combine-scheduler/26635/20) he said this:

> So to follow up here, there are some changes incoming in the regards to the way downstream events are propagated. We are now able to satisfy the constraint of 1.03 even if the DispatchQueue is concurrent or the OperationQueue is not a restriction of maxConcurrentOperations of 1, or for that matter any valid scheduler being concurrent; we will always send serialized events on that requested scheduler for `.receive(on:)`. The one remaining caveat that we deviate from the specification slightly is that upstream events such as `cancel()` and `request(_:)` in our world can happen concurrently. That being said we do handle them in a thread safe manner.

You can make your concurrency work in Xcode 11 beta 3 by dispatching to the concurrent queue, and then back to the main queue, from within your `Future`'s closure:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func delayAndDoubleNumber(_ int: Int) -> Future<Int, Never> {
    return Future<Int, Never> { complete in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            sleep(1)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                complete(.success(int * 2))
            }
        }
    }
}

let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

subject
    .flatMap { delayAndDoubleNumber($0) }
    .collect(4)
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print("Complete: \($0)") },
        receiveValue: { print("Received Value: \($0)") })

let canceller = (0 ..< 30).publisher().subscribe(subject)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the links to the swift.org board. Didn't know that about the serial queue requirement at this stage of the betas. This solution works, but it doesn't feel exclusively combine-y. I'd like to leave the question open incase Combine's functionality changes before the release this fall.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, this may be a flawed interpretation of the docs, but I think you should be using the `subscribe(on:)` operator instead of `receive(on:)`.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204758-subscribe):

> In contrast with receive(on:options:), which affects downstream messages, subscribe(on:) changes the execution context of upstream messages.

My interpretation of this is, if you want events from your `numbersSubject` to be emitted on your queue, you would use `subscribe(on:)`, for example:

```
numbersSubject
    .flatMap { number in
        return delayAndDoubleNumber(number)
    }
    .collect(4)
    .subscribe(on: processingQueue)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("Complete: \(completion)")
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Received Value: \(value)")
    })
```

Comment: With this solution, as opposed to the one proposed by Rob, calling cancel on the sink doesn't appear to cancel anything. The sink still receives all the values, and processes the finish message.